# How do I make a button appear and disappear?Libgdx

Tags: java, button, libgdx

I want my button to appear whenever an object reaches a certain position, that object is a sprite that is generated every second:

```
public void create() {
  if(spritePosition>700) {
    buttonObj.createButton();
  } 
}

public void render() {
  if (condition==true) {
    stage.draw();
  }
}
```

The problem is that when the games starts no Sprite is generated yet, so the result is an error. I'm also thinking of calling the `createButton()` method on the render method but it would generate a new button every frame because it's called constantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to let your button "disappear" is to just set its position to some position outside of the visible screen area.

For example something like:

```
buttonObj.setPosition(-1000, -1000);
```

To make it visible again you can just set the real coordinates again!

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the proper way of doing it but it's certainly the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public void create() {
    buttonObj.createButton();
    buttonObj.setVisible(false); 
}

public void render() {
  if (condition==true) {
    buttonObj.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All actors in Scene2d have the setVisible method. simply try :

```
yourButton.setVisible(true)
```

or

```
yourButton.setVisible(false);
```